# Fill an empty postgres database in Pyspark

Tags: postgresql, pyspark

I would like to put a Pyspark dataframe `json_df` into a totally empty postgres database (no schema and table). I use the following code but there is something wrong with the table selected in the option of the write statement. The error shows a driver issue but I have the driver updated so I assume it is just my code which is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
database = "postgres"

jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432;databaseName={database}"

schema = StructType([
  StructField('first_column', StringType(), True),
  StructField('second_columns', StringType(), True),
  ])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(),schema)

json_df.select("first_column","second_column").write.format("jdbc") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
  .option("user", user) \
  .option("dbtable", df) \
  .save()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "etl.py", line 98, in <module>
    .option("dbtable", df) \
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 825, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o74.save.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Edit:

After changing the code to:

```
json_df.write.format("jdbc") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
  .option("user", user) \
  .option("dbtable", "news_schema.json_df") \
    .save()
```

The error is:

```
 File "etl.py", line 104, in <module>
    .option("dbtable", "new_schema.json_df") \
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 825, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o53.save.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html, you should use `postgresql` instead of `postgres`, and no need to specify `databaseName=`

```
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{database}"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225320/discussion-on-answer-by-mck-fill-an-empty-postgres-database-in-pyspark).